# Cross Device Devlopment for Windows Devices - multiple sdk's?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-runtime, windows-phone

Couldn't find a direct answer for this...would like to get into windows device programming for some workplace solutions. I jumped onto google and typed in "Windows SDK" and I got found there are separate SDK's for Windows Phone 8, Surface RT, and Windows 8.

I thought to myself "this can not be true" so I hit the forums...haven't found anything relevant.

Does ANYONE know if there is an all-in-one solution for windows 8 programming that encompasses all devices? If I have to develop the same app 3 times to accommodate all three devices I am going to have to advise upper management against this decision.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is exactly what you need.

[Windows Phone 7/8 and Windows 8 Co-development](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Co-development_for_Windows_Phone_7/8_and_Windows_8_guide).

You should separate you code, move platform independent logic to [PCL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/gg597391%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

You'll have to develop different UIs for WP and WinRT anyway.